# Adding Business days to datetime column without using inbuilt function or loops

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a Date column for which I have to add N business days.
Following is the code I am currently using.

```
def workdays(start, add_days):
count = add_days
res = start
while count != 0:
    res += timedelta(days=1)
    weekday = res.weekday()
    if weekday >= 5:
        continue
    count -= 1
return res
```

But I have 1 million dates data and the runtime is around 20s for that.
So to improve the runtime I have to remove loops. Also I cannot use inbuilt functions like

( BDay() from pandas.tseries.offsets  )

Please help me.Thanks

Comment: why can you not use the built-in `BDay` from `pandas`?

Comment: This problem is a assignment and the instructions are not to use inbuilt fuction